# How do I dynamically switch between default Python versions?

Tags: python, linux, dynamic, version, switching

I know this question already [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108974/switch-versions-of-python), but it's really old and I know what I'm looking for. I've used an application earlier that let me very easily install any version of Python and set it to default with one command. I can't for the life of me remember the name, and for some reason I can't find it via Google either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [PythonBrew](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonbrew), perhaps?